# Breadcrumbs parent not shown

Tags: joomla-k2

I can see that breadcrumbs should/could support parent categories:
$path = modK2ToolsHelper::getCategoryPath($row->parent);

However i am unable to get more than 1 level of parent.
**Is this a configuration issue on my behalf?**
if so why is the top parent category hidden?

What i am wanting is top_parent->parent->child_item
what i current get is parent->child_item

Also i dont want to go hacking core files, as i would like to update and continue using K2

Comment: Tried in the forums - http://getk2.org/community/English-K2-Community/198464-breadcrumbs-parent#198464

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).